# Specify path for shared library on Linux in a C++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I successfully compile my first Shared Library with the **ld** commannd. It is located in the following path.

/home/user/code/lib/libMy-lib.so

Although when I try to use it in a project I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMy-lib
```

This it my compile line

```
g++ SuperProject.cpp -o SuperProject -L/home/user/code/lib -lMy-lib -I/home/user/code/includes
```

I've been following these two tutorial and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

- http://peon-developments.blogspot.ca/2011/07/creating-and-using-c-shared-libraries.html
- http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/so.html

Answer (score 1):

Set the path:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/code/lib

Comment: thx for the suggestion, but it does not work for me. This is what I have when I do printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/home/user/code/lib (note I have a colon before the first /)